# Regex: grep special character in HTML-Tags-Attributes

Tags: php, regex

The following regex does not work 100% correctly...

```
~<?<.*?(")|(\s)|(:)|(;)|(,).*?[>]~gm
```

in  this string

```
<span style="font-family: verdana,sans-serif;"><strike>Strike</strike></span>::<b><strike>Bold-Strike</strike></b>::<b><i><strike>Bold-Strike-Italic</strike></i></b>::<strike><b>Bold-Strike</b></strike><strike><b><i><u><font size="6"><strike><b>Bold-Strike-Font</b></strike></font></u></i></b></strike>::<u><strike>Strike2</strike></u>
```

I need to match all special character in the html-tags-attributes (`=`,`"`,`-`,`:`)

Comment: The whole expression doesn't make sense, what are you trying to accomplish ? Also FYI there is no `g` modifier in PHP/PCRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this regex:

```
(?:<|\G)[^<>=":,; -]*([ =":,;-](?=[^<>]*>))
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX8iR1)

The `\G` matches the end of the first match and allows you to get all the 'special characters' in the same tag.

Comment: @Nico By the way, do you still need help with the other question? I could not read the message properly on the other site because of the html tags.